# Store lxml.etree._ElementTree objects in dataframe: TypeError: can't pickle lxml.etree._ElementTree objects

Tags: python, pandas, lxml, pickle

I tried to store lxml.etree._ElementTree objects in a dataframe. Unfortunately the objects are not recognized by pandas. Is there a way to still store them in a dataframe or is there another way to store all the information in a single file with good read/write speed and filesize?

Here is an example to recreate the error:

```
import pandas as pd

import lxml
from lxml import etree

s = '''<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>'''

doc = etree.fromstring(s)
root = etree.ElementTree(doc)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = [["name1", "date1", root]], columns = ["name", "date", "root"])
df.to_pickle(r"D:\test\test.pkl")
# TypeError: can't pickle lxml.etree._ElementTree objects
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<...>", line 2, in <module>
    df.to_pickle(r"D:\test\test.pkl")

  File "...\Anaconda\envs\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2771, in to_pickle
    to_pickle(self, path, compression=compression, protocol=protocol)

  File "...\Anaconda\envs\...\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 76, in to_pickle
    f.write(pickle.dumps(obj, protocol=protocol))

TypeError: can't pickle lxml.etree._ElementTree objects
```

Comment: They got into the dataframe okay, its just that you can store the lxml objects via pickle. Since lxml elements still reference the orginal document, its not likely what you'd want to do anyway. You could just the store the original xml string (or reserialize the subtree).

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback, I am aware that it is in the df. My intention is to have a fast read/write format to store larger quantities of xmls with a decent filesize. Since I noticed extreme differences between csv and pkl in pandas in terms of speed .pkl made sense initially. So you would suggest saving the the string in the dataframe instead of the ElementTree or did I missunderstood you there?

Comment: @ tdelaney  Your comment brought me onto the right track I think. Thank you! I upvoted a few of your answers in other posts since I can't reward repution to a comment.

Comment: Yes, I think storing the string is better than trying to store a DOM. There are XML databases out there that may be handy, but I have no experience with them. How best to store the data depends on what you want to do with it later. That's a large topic, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future readers, fixed it by transforming the etree to string before saving:

```
df["root"] = df["root"].map(lambda x: etree.tostring(x, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
df.to_pickle(r"D:\test.pkl")


df = pd.read_pickle(r"D:\test.pkl")
df["root"] = df["root"].map(etree.fromstring).map(etree.ElementTree)
```